# remove polygon / polyline from a bing map

Tags: bing-maps

With the Bing v7 AJAX control, if it contains several polygons/polylines, and I want to remove all of them at once, how do I go about doing this?  I suppose I can loop through the map.Entities collection and inspect each to see if it is a poly* object, but I was wondering if there is an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there's a need to handle a group of elements easily I usually place them on an [EntityCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427616). Then, you can just hide/remove that layer.

Check out [this](http://www.garzilla.net/vemaps/Layers-via-the-Entity-Collection-with-Bing-Maps-7.aspx) example. It hides the entities instead of removing them, but the principle is the same.

Comment: +1. The whole purpose of EntityCollections is to allow you to manage elements as a group.